# Scala - Find the exact index of the current element of a List

Tags: scala, for-loop, indexof

I've got a problem when trying to find out the index of 10 (the last element) in this for loop

For example

```
val l: List[Int] = List(10, 1, 4, 5, 6, 10)
for(i <- l)
{
   println(i + " " + l.indexOf(i))
}
```

The output is

```
10 0
1 1
4 2
5 3
6 4
10 0
```

How to get `10 5` in the last line ?

Comment: Would probably be easiest to take a recursive approach with list destructuring, maintaining an accumulator on the number of indexes already processed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List(10, 1, 4, 5, 6, 10).zipWithIndex.foreach{ case(a, b) => println(a + " " + b)}
> 10 0
  1 1
  4 2
  5 3
  6 4
  10 5
```

You can use `zipWithIndex` to generate the `pair` of `value` and `index`.

Answer (score 1):

```
val l: List[Int] = List(10, 1, 4, 5, 6, 10)

for((v, i) <- l.zipWithIndex) {
  println(v + " " + l.indexOf(v, i))
}
```

Generating the current index and then using indexOf() to search from the current index forward will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a range to iterate instead:

```
let tempL = l;
let el;
for (i <- 0 until l.length) {
    el = tempL.head;
    prinln(i + " " + el);
    tempL = tempL.tail
}
```

Can probably be simplified, just an idea